# Remote Desktop Client perpetual update in App Store

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, software-update

The App Store icon in my Dock always has a little "1" badge on it indicating that 1 app is available for update. That 1 app is "Remote Desktop Client Update 3.7.1" via "Software Update."

However, when I click either "Update" or "Update All," it seems to update, but the "1" badge doesn't go away and the App Store perpetually shows that the Remote Desktop Client is always available for update. FYI: I have two Macs and this problem happens on only one of them.

Why is this the case? How can it be fixed?

Comment: have you try to restart? maybe its a bug.

Comment: Of course it's a bug. A restart didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more searching, I found [this](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#serversandenterprisesoftware) where I manually downloaded ARDC from and manually installed it. After re-running the App Store app, it now no longer shows ARDC needing to be updated.